# Unrecognized expression jquery attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the following error:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   [src$=="copyright.gif"] k.errorjquery_1_6_2_min.js:17
>   k.filterjquery_1_6_2_min.js:17 kjquery_1_6_2_min.js:17
>   c.querySelectorAll.kjquery_1_6_2_min.js:17
>   f.fn.extend.findjquery_1_6_2_min.js:17
>   e.fn.e.initjquery_1_6_2_min.js:16 ejquery_1_6_2_min.js:16 (anonymous
>   function)

when executing the following script:

```
var copyright = $('img[src$="copyright.gif"]').attr('src');
```

using the tag below:

```
<img border='0' src='/resources/copyright.gif' alt='copyright' />
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  I am using 1.6.2.min.js

Comment: in the error its saying that you have src$==" instead of src$="

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/3ngFE/

Comment: `$("img[src$='copyright.gif']")` notice the quotes and double quotes

Comment: @Laurence.  That is the error I get when I use the code listed in the question section.  Perhaps the jquery source that I have is corrupted.  I will re-download and try again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That works oh jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vw6TS/2/. Are you using your own local copy of jquery if so make sure its a complete file and not corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because in the code you're actually doing

```
$('img[src$=="copyright.gif"]').attr('src');
```

instead of what you posted, which is this

```
var copyright = $('img[src$="copyright.gif"]').attr('src');
```

Comment: Don't assume, i put `$('img[src$=="copyright.gif"]').attr('src');` into the console and got the same error.

Comment: yes but I commented because I wanted to make sure that the op's question wasnt a typo or if he was getting this error with the code he posted.

Comment: Gave you a +1 because it most like for now is the correct answer and I wouldnt want to double up on the same question

Comment: Perhaps my local copy is corrupted.  A straight copy and paste of what you have posted yields the same error.  I downloaded jquery source about 4 hours ago.  I will download the source and try again.